# How to get data from a service in ngOnInit Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, service, async-await

I've a problem trying to get data in ngOnInit from a http service. I need to set my data in a var when the component is fired, so I can use it in another functions.

I've achieved this by doing async ngOnInit, and receiving the response from a Promise function, but I dont think its a good practice ? How can I improve it?

Here is my code:

**COMPONENT.TS**

```
     async ngOnInit() {
        this.username = localStorage.getItem('username');
        this.segment.value = 'FUNCIONAL';
        this.categoria = this.segment.value;
        this.listadoClases = await this.claseServicio.obtenerListadoClases(this.categoria); // **Need to set this variable at onInit**
```

**SERVICE.TS**

```
    getClases(actividad) {
        return this.http.get(`https://anders-test.herokuapp.com/clases/obtenerPorCategoria/${actividad}`);
      }


      obtenerListadoClases(categoria) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          this.getClases(categoria).subscribe(data => {
            if (data) {
              resolve(data)
            }
          })
        })
      }
```

Im doing this because Im trying to learn/understand async/await. I want to level up my code a little bit.. But Im not getting the idea after reading a lot..

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: It's basically fine, although there's an easier way to convert an observable into a promise: just `return this.getClases(cetegoria).toPromise()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nyco, why on earth do you make the things so complex?

The service

```
  getClases(actividad) {
        return this.http.get(`https://anders-test.herokuapp.com/clases/obtenerPorCategoria/${actividad}`);
      }
```

The component

```
//inject the service in constructor
constructor(private service:Service){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.username = localStorage.getItem('username');
    this.segment.value = 'FUNCIONAL';
    this.categoria = this.segment.value;
    this.service.getClases(this.categoria).subscribe(res=>{
        this.categorias=res
    })
}
```

You should avoid subscribe in services except for some special function. Think that Angular is make over Observables. If you need convert an Observable in Promise, should be a good reason for this

Comment: Gotcha! Can you please add how I can make it if I use observables? I just want to get the whole idea of how to work my services

Comment: Nico, this.http.get return an Observable in self. In the guide: https://angular.io/guide/http you has info about httpClient. Yes, we can create an Observable using 'rxjs' "creations": https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/,  but httpClient methods **return Observables** too, see https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient. The 'rxjs' creations, are utils when we want,e.g. not return a value else an observable of the value -use 'of'-, or when we want create a timer -use `timer`-,etc

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient returns an Observable object in angular. You can just subscribe to it and will give you the response and works on multithread.
In this, you will avoid the user to wait until the response comes. It is a good practice and meanwhile, you could do other operations independent of the api response data.

But if you want to wait until the data are fetched from api then you can use Promise and it can be handled by keyword **then**.
In modern Javascript, you can handle it using **async/await**. Which is more look like synchronous code and easy to read and understand.

Please follow this

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.username = localStorage.getItem('username');
    this.segment.value = 'FUNCIONAL';
    this.categoria = this.segment.value;
    this.obtenerListadoClases();
```

> it is not a good practice to add async before ngOnInit

```
 async obtenerListadoClases() {
    try {
           this.listadoClases = await this.claseServicio.obtenerListadoClases(this.categoria);
        }).catch((e) => {
           console.log(e);
        });
  }
```

As HttpClient returns an Observable object in angular 5* in that case you have to make the method asynchronous which will return a promise. That you can do the way you have done.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.getClases(categoria).subscribe((res: any) => {
                resolve({status: 200, data: res});
            }, (error) => {
                resolve({status: 400, data:[]});
            },
            () => {
                resolve({status: 201, data:[]});
            });
    })
```

For more please check this out 
[Using async-await feature in Angular](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77)

Comment: "it is not a good practice to add async before ngOnInit" - care to explain, why?

Comment: I've done like you told me but on console.log it still shows undefined

 ngOnInit() {
    this.obtenerListadoClases();
    console.log(this.listadoClases, 'listadoclases'); // Undefined

Comment: @mbojko Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39492163/9739044

Comment: @NicoAybar please import it like this 

`import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';`
and implement it like this 

`export class YourrComponent implements OnInit {
}`

Comment: @sibabratswain I've that :/

Comment: @NicoAybar Please add a `try catch` block to check what is the error it return from the Promise. It might be you are not getting naything in data and in else condition you are not resolving the promise in your service.

Comment: @sibabratswain sorry, the link you provided doesn't state that "it is not a good practice to add async before ngOnInit". No wonder, considering it's an answer from September 2016, when there was no such thing as `async-await` in JavaScript.

Comment: @NicoAybar please follow the updated answer. Use the update Promise Code and let me know if it works.

Comment: @sibabratswain, an Observables is async

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the data and store it in a variable, the cleanest solution I could think about is to fire an http request [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) lifecycle method and store is in [Observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable).

For example:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.response$ = this.http.get('http://...');
}
```

Later on, you can turn the `response$` into promise with [toPromise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) method and use async/await with it.
Also, be careful if you use the `response$` multiple times, because it will trigger multiple http requests, you can use the [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) operator like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.response$ = this.http.get('http://...').pipe(shareReplay(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* On SERVICE */

 getOffice(id: string) {
    return this.firestore.collection('offices').doc(id).valueChanges();
 }

/* On COMPONENT */

 ngOnInit(): void {
    let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.service.getOffice(id).subscribe((val) => 
      this.officeDetails = val;
      console.log(this.officeDetails);
    });
 }
```